Why is my Thevenin voltage result wrong in LTspice?
I want to simulate the Thevenin voltage of the circuit below, where Z2 is the load, in LTspice. Does anyone know what is wrong here? The result is incorrect; the correct Thevenin voltage should be approximately 403.43<-25.91°. I have been checking a lot but couldn't find where the mistake is.



This is my calculation using Mathematica:

This is the file:
Version 4
SHEET 1 1132 680
WIRE 16 112 -16 112
WIRE 64 112 16 112
WIRE 240 112 144 112
WIRE 576 112 496 112
WIRE 736 112 640 112
WIRE 1024 112 992 112
WIRE 1040 112 1024 112
WIRE 992 144 992 112
WIRE -16 160 -16 112
WIRE 240 160 240 112
WIRE 496 160 496 112
WIRE 736 160 736 112
WIRE 992 256 992 224
WIRE -16 288 -16 240
WIRE 240 288 240 240
WIRE 240 288 -16 288
WIRE 496 288 496 240
WIRE 496 288 240 288
WIRE 736 288 736 240
WIRE 736 288 496 288
WIRE -16 336 -16 288
FLAG -16 336 0
FLAG 240 112 V1
FLAG 496 112 V2
FLAG 992 256 0
FLAG 944 160 V1
FLAG 944 208 V2
FLAG 1024 112 Vth
FLAG 16 112 Vin
SYMBOL voltage -16 144 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 100 30
SYMBOL res 160 96 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL ind 480 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 20
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0 Rpar=0 Cpar=0
SYMBOL cap 640 96 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value {1/25}
SYMBOL current 240 240 R180
WINDOW 0 24 80 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName I1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL e 992 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName E2
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage 736 144 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 80 -45
TEXT -16 408 Left 2 !.ac list {1/(2*pi)}

This is netlist file:
V1 Vin 0 0 AC 100 30
R1 V1 Vin 10
L1 V2 0 20 Rser=0
C1 N001 V2 {1/25}
I1 0 V1 5
E2 Vth 0 V1 V2 1
V2 N001 0 0 AC 80 -45
.ac list {1/(2*pi)}
.backanno
.end


Inductors have parasitic resistance by default in LTSpice. Try setting RPAR and RSER to zero explicitly for L1 and see if you get the expected answer.

@Good point, but I just tried it and it doesn't seem to have any effect.

@internet You don't want to give us the wiring/drawing file. That's for display purposes. The netlist tells us what Spice sees. Please add the netlist to wiring/drawing file. Is the load, Z2, supposed to be inserted? Or left out?

Show how you got 403.43<-25.91° as an answer. From a purely AC standpoint (DC voltages ignored), I get the same results as LTspice using pencil, paper, and a hand calculator.

@qrk I just used my stupid calculator: $$\begin{align*}\text{(86.6025404+j50) + 510} &= \text{136.60254 + j50 (145.465646} \angle \text{20.1039094}^\circ)\\text{(56.5685425 - j56.5685425)(j20 / (j20 - j25))} &= \text{-226.27417 + j226.27417 (320} \angle \text{135}^\circ)\\text{(136.60254 + j50)-(-226.27417 + j226.27417)}&= \text{362.87671 - j176.27417 (403.425445}\angle\text{-25.9090334}^\circ)\end{align*}$$Looks like a match to what the question says about it so long as the load isn't attached. I've not tried to use LTspice, though. But I seem to replicate what is written in the question.

@periblepsis Thanks for the double-check. I added the netlist. The load is removed as I calculated the Thevenin voltage.

@internet  I would still post your hand calculations just so we can take a look.  I don't believe there is a mistake in how you're setting up the circuit in LTspice, so it's possible the discrepancy is how you do it in the hand calcs.  Also, how do you know which result is incorrect?  Do you have the answer key in the textbook which says it's indeed 403.43/_-25.91°?

@SteKulov I just added my calculation. I don't have the answer key. I was trying to simulate it for fun while seeing the problem someone posted. I think several people got the same calculation result.

@SteKulov I posted my calculations. It's straight-forward. But if I made a mistake (possible) you should be able to find it in the calcs I show above. It's just, on left, taking the voltage source and adding 5 amps times 10 Ohms to it since that's what the current source is doing (if I'm not mistaken -- please verify for yourself, of course.) On right, it's just the voltage source against a voltage divider equation. Again, check how I write it up to see if you disagree or not. Then I take the difference. But two people can be wrong and in exactly the same way. Extra checks always welcome.

@internet I am not going to play with LTspice yet. But have you tried to include the .options plotwinsize=0 card? LTspice loves to compress its floating point data. That card tells it to not compress the FP stuff. Might make a difference.

@periblepsis  I'm bad at KCL and phasor math, so I was hoping someone else would do it.  Haha.

@internet It's really cool that you can get this kind of support when you need it. Ste Kulov really put down all the details for you. Cool! Best wishes and I'm so glad that you were able to get all this sorted out. :) +1 to your question!

@periblepsis yeah, I saw his good answers to LTspice questions before. And also thank you for your help!

I believe I found the problem.  I originally assumed that the current source has a DC value of 5A since it shows no angle after its value.  However, it looks like it's supposed to be 5A AC.  Therefore, we need to make a small change to your schematic for the current source.


Cute. I just did the same thing and got this which is just slightly different. I wonder if we are using different versions. I'm using the x64 version called 17.1.5.

@periblepsis  It's cuz we set our inductor ESR explicitly to zero.

Perfect!! Yeah. That's the difference! I'll add a +1. I love that you nailed all the details down!

Thanks! I can have a good sleep now.

For clarification, the schematic file provided by the questioner already had the inductor resistance set to zero.  I just used that file directly in my answer.

I considered the circuit transformed according to Laplace and then I applied Thevenin's theorem twice. Finally I considered the voltage phasors. What do you think? See figure:


I'm not sure where is the mistake but your final result is not correct.

....I don't see any errors....

Ah, I misread it, VAB is not the Thevenin. Yeah your thevenin is also same as mine.
